# UnsupportedCommandException error performing touchactions in iOS device using Appium

Tags: appium, xcuitest

I am using appium version 2.5.1

And while running the touchAction to click outside the calender prompt to close the calender in iOS device,i am getting error as-

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unhandled endpoint: /session/4D8B61E6-316C-4A73-AC31-A76A27216AE4/wda/touch/perform -- http://127.0.0.1:8100/ with parameters {
    wildcards =     (
        "session/4D8B61E6-316C-4A73-AC31-A76A27216AE4/wda/touch/perform"
    );
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'QB-TP3-3039.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10dc:713e:ba86:c97%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Session ID: 36c51a8b-504b-4d4c-acbf-d158d7317ca4
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```